# How to add comment form in ListView Django?

Tags: python, django

**Into**: I have a queryset of multiple posts in listviewpage. i want to add comment form with each of post in `listviewpage` instead of `detailpageview`. i also include html form inside forloop of posts list

**Problem**: The code below is getting error `'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'get'`

I would be grateful for any help.

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def ListViewPage(request):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    comment = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            pk = request.POST.get('pk')
            post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            return ValidationError(f'No Post by id {pk}')


        if comment.is_valid():
            com = comment.save(commit=False)
            com.posts = post
            com.save()

    context = {
        'posts': queryset,
        'form': comment
    }
    return render(request, 'post_list.html', context)
```

**post_list.html**

```
{% for object in sales %}
<div class="hpanel hblue">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="project-label">Saler</div>
            <small>{{ object.user }}</small>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="project-label">Timestamp</div>
            <small>{{ object.created_on|naturalday }}</small>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="project-label">Product</div>
            <small>{{ object.created_on|naturalday }}</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="." method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="comments" id="id_comments" cols="30" rows="2" required class="form-control"
                placeholder="comments..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can *not* return aq `ValidationError` in the view, you need to return a HTTP response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *not* return aq `ValidationError` in the view, you need to return a HTTP response, or raise a `Http404` exception for example:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def ListViewPage(request):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            pk = request.POST.get('pk')
            post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404(f'No Post by id {pk}')
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.posts = post
            comment_form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    context = {
        'posts': queryset,
        'form': comment_form
    }
    return render(request, 'post_list.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: Dear it's getting this error `No Post by id None`

Comment: @afi: that means that in your POST request there is no `pk` item, so `request.POST` does not contain a key `pk`. This of course depends on how you render the HTML form.

Comment: please take a look my question is updated!

Comment: @afi: well your form does not contain any `<input>` element with `name="pk">`, hence you do not submit the primary key.

Comment: please would you like to explain that how can pass the "pk" inside html form?

Comment: @afi: you make an element `<input type="hidden" name="pk" value="{{ some-expr }}">` with `some-expr` an expression that evaluates to the primary key of the post you wish to update.

Comment: i want to do like facebook. the facebook home page has multiple post and each post has there comment section where we can add comment for each post....

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Please can you share an example of the expression to pass in value={{  post.pk  }} this what i did and i got a whole bunch of numbers in all the comment field.

Comment: @AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma: I propose that you ask a new question with details about the view, template, etc. and explain *what* you aim to achieve.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Actually i am trying to do the something, have users on my app comment and like on the list view, but it wont work after trying the solution.  its been somewhat challenging. so i was looking for answers on here that i came across this solution and tried. i didn't want to post another question, then it would be a duplicate. . i would want to know how to write the expression for the value={{      }} since i get a number in the comment box when i do this value ={{ post.pk  }}